# Joining Three tables without a matching column

Tags: sql, join, ssis, dimension

I want to create a geography dimension using ssis 2008.I have 3 table sources.

Here is the explanation

```
Table 1 = Country: country code and country name 
Table 2 = Post code: post code and city name
Table 3 = Territory : Territory code and Territory name
```

Here is how data looks

```
[Table 1= Country]

      code name  
     ------------------
       US | United states 
       CA | Canada 

[Table 2= post code] 

      Code    city  
     ---------------
       1000  |  Paris
       2000  |  Niece

[Table 3= Territory]

       Code    name
      ----------------
       N    |   North
       S    |   south
```

As you can see there is no single common column, I want to group these 3 tables in the same geography dimension.

So, how can I do it ?

Also,The use of this geography dim will be when another dimension for example customer dimension.we want to know the revenue of client according to his geography or the the top salespersons in some city.

and in both customer and salesperson tables you can find the those  3 as foreign keys.

Comment: Do YOU know all the post codes that belong to a particular city or all cities in a country? How do you expect a machine to do it *without* this intermediate knowledge? (i.e. foreign keys etc). If missing data is captured, a computer can't be expected to *fill in the gaps* IMHO

Comment: There are some post code that belong to the same city.As I explained those 3 tables can be somehow linked in the customer table or sales line tables...

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* need a "common column" shared by all three tables.

You *do* need a "column column" between each *pair* of tables.  How else are you going to link them???

Q: Is there any column that links "Country" to "City"?  You should have a "country code" column in "city".

Q: Is there any way to link "Territory" with *either* "post code" or "country"?  If "Yes": problem solved.  Please list the fields.  If "No" ... then you need to change your schema.

Comment: No, there is no column that links country to city or country to territory.How ever, They all some kind of linked in the customer table or the sales person tables.for example in customer table, there is name,city,country,territory

Comment: I think the best answer after you guys told that impossible to join if there no common colunm is to create for each dimension customer and salesperson its own fields (country,city....).

What do you think about this solution ?

Comment: Country code (e.g. "US") and/or city code (e.g. "1000") - yes.  You obviously can't link the tables unless you have something to link with :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on you comment to paulsm4 you then want to use those tables that hold the linking information to join to each of the above 3 tables.

On the other hand if you really want to join just those three tables

select * from Country
full outer join [Post code]
  on 'a' = 'a'
full outer join Territory
  on 'b' = 'b'

Comment: I tried it but it gives me duplicated rows as for the third table, it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table dim.geography (geoID int,citycode int, countrycode char(2),territorycode char(1))

insert into dim.geography (select city as citycode,country as countrycode, territory as territorycode from Customer union select city, country,territory from salesperson)
```

Assuming here that Customer and salesperson tables hold the codes and not the values for country,territory, and country.

The code above will build a dimension for the geography you want.  Of course if you add any additional unique city,country,territory codes into the customer/salesperson tables you will need to add it to your dimension.  This is just an initial load.  You may also need to modify the code to account for nulls in any of the three qualifiers.